# How can I hide and display part of the form on a condition?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to use the same form to perform two different operations, and hide and display part of the form on a condition. Let's say if the text of the submit button is "SAVE" `admissionNumber` input field will not display but if the button text of the submit button is "UPDATE" `admissionNumber` input field will display. Below is the code sample

**registerForm.html the same for being used to register and update student information**

```
    <div layout:fragment="content" class="container mySpace">

        <form method="post" th:object="${student}" th:action="@{/register}">
            <div class="card cardspace">
                <h5 class="card-header" th:text="${chead}"></h5>
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <div class="row">
```

i want to be able hide admissionNumber field if the btname is save and display it if the btname changes to update

```
                                <div class="form-group col" th:if="${btnname} == 'Submit'">
                                    <label for="admissionNumber">Admission Number</label> <input
                                        type="text" class="form-control" id="admissionNumber"
                                        th:field="*{admissionNumber}">
                                    <div class="text text-danger"
                                        th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('admissionNumber')}"
                                        th:errors="*{admissionNumber}"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col" th:unless="${btnname} == 'Update'">
                                    <label for="admissionNumber">Admission Number</label> <input
                                        type="text" class="form-control" id="admissionNumber"
                                        th:field="*{admissionNumber}">
                                    <div class="text text-danger"
                                        th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('admissionNumber')}"
                                        th:errors="*{admissionNumber}"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="firstName">First Name</label> <input type="text"
                                        class="form-control" id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}">
                                    <div class="text text-danger"
                                        th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}"
                                        th:errors="*{firstName}"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label> <input type="text"
                                        class="form-control" id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}">
                                    <div class="text text-danger"
                                        th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}"
                                        th:errors="*{lastName}"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" th:text="${btnname}"></button>
 </form>
```

**student controller class**

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentServices studentServices;
```

**displays the registration form**

```
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showStudentRegistrationForm(Model model ) {
        
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        model.addAttribute("chead", "Student Enrollment");// for card-header title h5 tag
        model.addAttribute("btnname", "Submit"); // for button text
        return "views/studentRegistrationForm";
    }
```

**displays the edit or update form**

```
    @GetMapping("/editStudent")
    public String showStudentRegistrationEditForm(Model model ) {
        
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        model.addAttribute("chead", "Edit Student Enrollment");
        model.addAttribute("btnname", "Update");
        return "views/studentRegistrationForm";
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify where you are having a problem? You are already using the `th:if="${...}"` syntax. Are you not able to use that to implement the required logic, here? Something like `th:if="${btnname} == 'UPDATE'"` in the relevant `<div>`?

Comment: Yes I tried something like that but it didn't work

Comment: Can you clarify where you are having a problem? Can you (1) show what you tried, and (2) describe what "it didn't work" means in this case? For example, were there any errors in the application log or in the browser console? What behavior did you see?

Comment: i have edited the code to show what i was trying to implement but is not working as expected.

Comment: In the text of your question, you describe the possible button display values as "SAVE" and "UPDATE". In your code you are using "Submit" and "Update". Those are 4 different values. It would also help if you explain what you mean by "it is not working as expected". What actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

what you want is `th:if` tag, you got it almost right but whole wxpression needs to be in brackets `th:if="${btnname == 'Submit'}"`